# Где и как, лучше хранить длинный цветной текст?

Tags: java, android

Делаю, что-то вроде книги с кучей разделов. Разделы большие. Текст цветной с отступами и курсивами. Смотрю в сторону json. Но один раздел - это получается одна очень длинная строка. Размер текста в будущем приложении будет меняться. Еще советуют WebView, но в интернете мало информации. Вот и прошу совет, что лучше json, WebView или есть еще другой способ? Сейчас текст хранится в string (html), вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните html файлы в папке assets. 
Потом в вебвью можно их открыть.

Вот так:

```
...

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/example.html");

...
```

Ну или загрузить как строку и вставить в TextView:

```
try
{
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open("file:///android_asset/example.html");

    String html = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

    myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
    myTextView.setText("Ошибка при загрузке!");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хотел только уточнить, а в чем преимущество webView перед json?

Comment: Начнем с того, что нельзя сравнивать эти понятия. WebView - это по сути браузер. Json - это формат данных. Просто если текст в Html, то логично хранить его как Html.